# ionic 3 Call-Number plugin issue

Tags: ionic3

Ionic 3 i m using call-number plugin . but it show error

ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at CallNumber.callNumber

```
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number/ngx';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public httpClient: HttpClient, 
public callNumber: CallNumber) { }


  CallNumber(){

  this.callNumber.callNumber("18001010101", true)
 .then(res => console.log('Launched dialer!', res))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error launching dialer', err));


       }
}
```

Comment: Are you check it phone or browser?

Comment: in browser its showing error . also check it in android not working

Comment: Its error for browser or mobile phone

Answer (score 0):

you need to create instance of CallNumber in constructor

```
private callNumber: CallNumber
```

than your function looks like this

```
fnCallNumber(){
this.callNumber.callNumber("18001010101", true)
.then(res => console.log('Launched dialer!', res))
.catch(err => console.log('Error launching dialer', err));

}
```

now call these function in constructor or any click event want you want

```
this.fnCallNumber()
```

Comment: already add in constructor . same error i thing its issue in cordova version or in call-number plugin version .

Comment: if follow following step than it should be worked in my case it's working try to copy and paste my code

Comment: have you import that plugin in module.ts file ?

Comment: edit the question i attach the home.ts and also copy paste the exact code its not working . also import in app.module.ts . not working !

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are using a plugin that is not compatible with you application version. I got this same error. I'm using ionic 4...

Try run:

> npm install --save @ionic-native/call-number@4

Use this import without 'ngx':

> import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number';

And remember to put 'public callNumber: CallNumber' as PRIVATE.

in app.module.ts:

```
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number';

providers: [
StatusBar,
SplashScreen,
CallNumber,
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
```

]

Comment: I got this error right after adding CallNumber to my `app.module.ts` file. I didn't even get the chance to add it to my `home.module.ts` when this error showed up.